# Disk cache of Python packages from requirements.txt

Tags: python, linux, pip, package

Assume I built a `requirements.txt` file like this...

```
decorator==3.4.0
flup>=1.0.2
Werkzeug==0.9.4
argparse==1.2.1
Mako==0.9.0
Jinja2==2.7.1
Flask==0.10.1
itsdangerous==0.23
WTForms==1.0.5
Flask_WTF==0.9.3
```

I want to avoid problems with finding specific package versions.

Is there a simple way to stuff all the required packages into a disk archive without downloading them individually from pypi?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `download-cache` option in `~/.pip.conf`, this will store those packages that you install (their downloaded archives), and you can install from them later:

```
[global]
default-timeout = 60
respect-virtualenv = true
download-cache = /home/foo/bar/.pip/cache
log-file = /home/foo/bar/.pip/pip.log
build = /home/foo/bar/.pip/build

[install]
use-mirrors = true
```

You can also create your own [pypi server](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pypiserver#installation-and-usage-quickstart) and then maintain your own version of packages.

At work I prefer this option as it allows me to use the standard Python distutils to distribute and install packages which I do not want to put on the global cheese shop.

Comment: This seems to work on both windows & unix. Good point about `pip.conf`

Comment: The location of the config file should be `~/.pip/pip.conf` instead of `~/.pip.conf`.